# ABAddressBook get birthday property

Tags: iphone, xcode, addressbook

I'm trying to get the birthday property from ABAddressBook on my iphone. I've looked through some discussions over the web and mostly recommends the same answer, which I have tried myself as below. But this still doesn't work for me so I wonder if i missed something else....

```
        dayFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease];
    [self.dayFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d"];        

    NSString* today = [dayFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"today:%@", today);
    NSLog(@"date:%@", [NSDate date]); // this works fine


    NSDate *bday = (NSDate*)ABRecordCopyValue(personRecord,kABPersonBirthdayProperty);
    NSLog(@"bdayyyy:%@", bday); // this doesn't work.


    NSString* personBday = [dayFormatter stringFromDate:bday];
    NSLog(@"Bday:%@", personBday);
```

any help is much appreciated.. Thanks.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what means "it does not work"? Are there compile errors, runtime errors? What is the output? What have you already tried?

Comment: sorry this was unclear.... in the above code, 'bday' is printed as "(null)" by the console. On the other hand, 'today' is printed correctly (today's date & time). Did I call the ABRecordCopy Value incorrectly?

Comment: no errors, just that it returns NULL.

Comment: where do you get personRecord from? does it point to a valid location?

Comment: maybe the birthday property is not set, then it returns nil

Comment: Hi Axel and Phix23, I give the whole piece of code as below for more information about my code. Please have a look....

Comment: Phix23, could you please tell the meaning of 'birthday property is not set' ? I'd like to check for any clue. thanks.

Comment: most likely the contact record that you are accessing does not have a birthday defined and so the NSDate* bday variable is nil; the code that you have is exactly what I use and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
NSDate* birthDate = (__bridge_transfer NSDate*)ABRecordCopyValue(addressBookContact, kABPersonBirthdayProperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 ABAddressBookRef myAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
 NSArray *allPeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(myAddressBook);

 for (id record in allPeople) {
     NSMutableDictionary *newRecord = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
     CFTypeRef bDayProperty = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)record, kABPersonBirthdayProperty);

     if (ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)record, kABPersonBirthdayProperty)) 
       {
         NSDate *date=(NSDate*)bDayProperty;
         [newRecord setObject:date forKey:@"birthDate"];
         date=nil;
         [date release]; 
     }
    CFRelease(myAddressBook);
  }
```